# Can とても be used with [大好]{だいす}き or [大嫌]{だいきら}い?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

とても means "very"
[好]{す}き means "like"
[大好]{だいす}き means "like very much"

If I really like something can I use とてもとても大好きです ?

Comment: This seems like a problem of "ungradable adjectives".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Google says yes](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%22), to the tune of 1 million hits. A lot of the time it's used to describe how much you like something (とても大好きなお店). I presume that you were asking "Can you say totemo daisuki desu to someone". You can say that too (あなたがとても大好きです).

[Totemo daikirai](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E5%A4%A7%E5%AB%8C%E3%81%84%22) doesn't have as big a number of hits in Google.

Someone else will have to confirm this, but it sounds sort of childish. Maybe because the feeling is so strong.

Comment: I think you're on to it. There's nothing preventing you from saying とても大好き, but it does sounds a bit overboard. Not really childish (I'm sure many if not most of the people you found using it on Google aren't children), but maybe still somewhat like saying "a lot a lot" in English.

Answer (score 12):

> can I use “Totemo totemo daisuki desu”?

Whether you can use it or not depends on the context.

I think that “totemo daisuki” is redundant and therefore it is better to use either “totemo suki” (without dai-) or “daisuki” (without totemo) when some formalness is required.  However, in informal contexts, there is nothing wrong with using the redundant expression to emphasize how much you like it.  Using an informal expression can sometimes even imply that you really mean it (to the extent that you do not care about avoiding redundant expressions).

The same applies to “totemo daikirai,” too.

Answer (score -1):

I mean, totemo daisuki is in the lyrics of the Doraemon theme song, so... I would say yes, you can use it...